# exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes on Mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have to query a mongodb database

I'm doing this :

```
 var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("origine", sOrigin)
              & BsonDocument.Parse("{$expr: {$ne:['$crc_n', '$crc_n_1']} }");

  var sort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Ascending("update_date");

 List<BsonDocument> docs = collection.Find(filter).Sort(sort)
                .Limit(5000)
                .ToList();
```

But I have this message :

```
 Command find failed: Executor error during find command :: caused by :: Sort 
exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. 
Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.."}
```

I don't want to change the limit or to custom the server. I want to manage by code.

Do I Have to use thread with a smaller limit ?

Do I have to use a ConcurrentBag and query my database ?

What Can I do without touching the server ?

Answer (score 0):

The error messages states the solution:

> Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in..

The `Find` method provides optional parameter `FindOptions`, see [Find Method](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.6/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Find__1.htm).

However, according [FindOptions Class](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.6/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FindOptions.htm) option `allowDiskUse` is not supported. You have to test, perhaps it is just a lack of documentation.

Otherwise use [IMongoCollectionExtensions.Aggregate Method](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.6/apidocs/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Aggregate.htm), the `AggregateOptions` class supports property `AllowDiskUse`

Simply surround your condition by `$match`, i.e. `"{$match: {$expr: {$ne:['$crc_n', '$crc_n_1']} } }"`

**Update:**  The links in my answer refer to C# Driver 2.6. In more recent version property `allowDiskUse` is supported: [FindOptions Class (2.11)](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FindOptions_2.htm)